# serving up a png file via ifstream

Tags: c++, http

This seems like a really simple task, so bear with me.  I'm trying to extend a server which serves up files and webpages.  Currently the server gets an HTTP request, parses it, and calls a function called sendFile:

```
void sendFile(ostream& ostr, std::string filename) {
    std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary);
    ostr << ifs.rdbuf();
}
```

This scheme currently works fine for text files like javascript and css which are in the same directory as the server binary.  But when I try to serve up a png file, the browser sits forever.  It seems like the difference is that the png file is not a text file, but if this is indeed the problem, what should I be using instead of ifstream?  I see that the std::ios_base::binary flag is specified.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be setting the length and the mime type in the http headers.